# Keycloak: testing with FluentTestsHelper

Tags: spring-boot, testing, keycloak

Keycloak becomes more and more popular to use with Spring Boot apps.
But, as it is often the case, the documentation needs to be updated and is missing a lot of features to be documented or updated. It's the case of the testing chapter. Today, unfortunately, I didn't find any working library, an example that would make it possible. Even provided by keycloak [quick-starts](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts) projects [fail](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-15565).

So the question is how today is possible to test Keycloak authentication (writing controller tests) in spring-boot API app? Are there any available libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I use https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons and more specifically the `KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor` class.

Example:

```
   static KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor createAuth(String authServerUserId, String role, String givenName, String familyName, String email) {
        return new KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor()
                .roles("user", role)
                .name(email)
                .accessToken(accessToken -> {
                    accessToken.setSubject(authServerUserId);
                    accessToken.setGivenName(givenName);
                    accessToken.setFamilyName(familyName);
                })
                .idToken(idToken -> {
                    idToken.setSubject(authServerUserId);
                    idToken.setGivenName(givenName);
                    idToken.setFamilyName(familyName);
                });
    }
```

In your controller test:

```
        mockMvc.perform(get("/admin")
                                .with(createAuth(...)))
               .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, at least in its `2.3.4` version, there is no empty constructor for `KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor`, idem for methods called on `idToken`, - they do not exist.

Comment: I am using version `2.0.0` currently with Keycloak 9.

Comment: Too outdated, Keycloak has already `11.0.2` version.

Comment: I've already tried the following libs: [keycloak-mock](https://github.com/TNG/keycloak-mock), [testcontainers-keycloak](https://github.com/dasniko/testcontainers-keycloak), without success :(.

Comment: I provide with MockMvc fluent API sample here https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2-test-webmvc-addons/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc/keycloak/web/GreetingControllerMockMvcPostProcessorTest.java . That said, I personally use annotations only as it allows to test not only `@Controller` but also other `@Component` types with security (`@Service`, `@Repository`, ...)

Comment: As side note, if you  `@Import(ServletKeycloakAuthUnitTestingSupport.UnitTestConfig.class)`, then you can just `@Autowired BeanFactory beanFactory;` and in each `@Test`: `beanFactory.getBean(KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor.class);`

Comment: Weird enough, your [example](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2-test-webmvc-addons/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc/keycloak/web/GreetingControllerMockMvcPostProcessorTest.java) looks completely different from your solution above...

Comment: In my case, to get a token from Keycloak, I just POST `grant_type`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `username` and `password`. I can't see how it could be applied to one of your solutions above... Any tips?

Comment: The aim here is not to mimic an authorization code flow (sure you're not using deprecated flow, are you?) to get a JWT from Keycloak and then have it decoded, validated, parsed  into a `KeycloakAuthenticationToken` and finally injected in the security context but to directly build a `KeycloakAuthenticationToken`. See keycloak source for more info about their `Authentication` impl: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/spring-security/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/token/KeycloakAuthenticationToken.java

Comment: @ch4mp: What is still unclear for me: looking at the test [example](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/b55c33257cfbb08e27e7b0d5dffc9e43315dfa59/spring-security-oauth2-test-webmvc-addons/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc/keycloak/web/GreetingControllerAnnotatedTest.java#L66) and the [controller](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2-test-webflux-addons/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webflux/web/GreetingController.java) under the test, I can't see `secured-route` you test, why `JwtDecoder jwtDecoder` is not used?

Comment: `secured-route` is secured at servlet filter level, configured in [KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://git.io/JUujn). `JwtDecoder` is mocked to prevent resource-server (your spring service) to contact authorization-server (Keycloak) at startup (and throw SocketException because it can't reach it)

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement [Wim Deblauwe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40064/wim-deblauwe) answer for version 2.3.4 of https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons:

`createAuth` can't be static any-more because of `KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor` requiring a `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` and being injected with `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)`.

Important steps are

1. `@Import({ ServletKeycloakAuthUnitTestingSupport.UnitTestConfig.class})`
2. `@Autowired BeanFactory beanFactory;`
3. get `KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor` fresh instance with `beanFactory.getBean(KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor.class)` and configure it

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = GreetingController.class)
@Import({
        ServletKeycloakAuthUnitTestingSupport.UnitTestConfig.class,
        KeycloakSpringBootSampleApp.KeycloakConfig.class })
public class GreetingControllerMockMvcPostProcessorTest {
    @MockBean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    @Autowired
    BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    // to take @Wim Deblauwe sample, but could use any other helper method or none at all
    KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor createAuth(String authServerUserId, String role, String givenName, String familyName, String email) {
        return beanFactory.getBean(KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor.class)
                .authorities("user", role)
                .accessToken(accessToken -> {
                    accessToken.setSubject(authServerUserId);
                    accessToken.setGivenName(givenName);
                    accessToken.setFamilyName(familyName);
                    accessToken.setPreferredUsername(email);
                })
                .idToken(idToken -> {
                    idToken.setSubject(authServerUserId);
                    idToken.setGivenName(givenName);
                    idToken.setFamilyName(familyName);
                    idToken.setPreferredUsername(email);
                });
    }

    KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor foo() {
        return createAuth("42", "ROLE_TEST", "Foo", "Bar", "fbar@test.pf");
    }

    @Test
    public void whenAuthenticatedWithKeycloakAuthenticationTokenThenCanGreet() throws Exception {
        mockMvc
            ...
            .with(foo())
            ...;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** There is already a helper method on `ServletKeycloakAuthUnitTestingSupport` to get a new `KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor` from the BeanFactory.

Considering the comments below, I just (version `2.4.0`) renamed it from `keycloakAuthenticationToken()` to `authentication()`. So Instead of `@Autowired BeanFactory beanFactory;` you can `@Autowired ServletKeycloakAuthUnitTestingSupport keycloak;` and then, [as updated sample demonstrates](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2-test-webmvc-addons/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc/keycloak/web/GreetingControllerMockMvcPostProcessorTest.java), just

```java
    mockMvc.perform(get(...).with(keycloak.authentication()))...
```

Fluent, isn't it?

Complete sample (note I import `ServletKeycloakAuthUnitTestingSupport` instead of just `ServletKeycloakAuthUnitTestingSupport.UnitTestConfig` this time)

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = GreetingController.class)
@Import({
        ServletKeycloakAuthUnitTestingSupport.class,
        KeycloakSpringBootSampleApp.KeycloakConfig.class })
public class GreetingControllerMockMvcPostProcessorTest {
    @MockBean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    @Autowired
    ServletKeycloakAuthUnitTestingSupport keycloak;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void whenAuthenticatedWithKeycloakAuthenticationTokenThenCanGreet() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/greet").with(keycloak.authentication()
                        .authorities("AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL", "USER")
                        .accessToken(token -> token.setPreferredUsername("ch4mpy")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(startsWith("Hello ch4mpy! You are granted with ")))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL")))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("USER"))));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - it looks less and less Java :(. I wonder what values should be passed to `accessToken` and ìdToken` in your example: ```accessToken(accessToken -> {
                    accessToken.setSubject(authServerUserId);
                    accessToken.setGivenName(givenName);
                    accessToken.setFamilyName(familyName);
                })
                .idToken(idToken -> {
                    idToken.setSubject(authServerUserId);
                    idToken.setGivenName(givenName);
                    idToken.setFamilyName(familyName);
                });````

Comment: Trying to read it in English and unfortunately, it sounds like a real 'sharabia'

Comment: Why on Earth should I set `setPreferredUsername`, `setFamilyName`, etc. ?

Comment: Well, this is functional java. What people opting for "fluent" APIs are usually seeking. Regarding the `accessToken` and `idToken` APIs, I'm sticking to Keycloak token structure, which is a quite strict OAuth2 / OpenID implementation with private claims in addition. So basically, read the specs or inspect the tokens delivered by your keycloak instance with any tool like https://jwt.io/

Comment: "Why on Earth should I set setPreferredUsername, setFamilyName, etc. ?" Because you  are building a `KeycloakAuthenticationToken`...

Comment: It looks really awkward `keycloak.keycloakAuthenticationToken()` to return an instance of   `KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor`, imho, wrong naming?

Comment: `KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor` is a MockMvc RequestPostProcessor designed to configure and then inject a `KeycloakAuthenticationToken` in the test security-context. I don't really get what is awkward in the namings, but open to any suggestions...

Comment: Logically, when you call `user.getAddress()` you expect to get his address, no matter as a String or a POJO `Address`, not an instance of `MyFavoritLivingPlace`, it is just a personal opinion. Coding a lot in Ruby, for me it is totally logical to name methods and classes so that when reading them in English could give a clear idea of what it is about. So, in case of `keycloak.keycloakAuthenticationToken()`, I'd expect to get a token instead of an instance of `KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor` that I have no idea what it does.

Comment: But it is just out of the context. I'm trying to understand your code and miserably fail.

Comment: `keycloakAuthenticationToken()` returns an object to configure a ... `KeycloakAuthenticationToken`. This configurer object being an instance of `KeycloakAuthRequestPostProcessor` is mostly a spring's internal implementation detail and of no importance for test writer whose only intention is to easily fine tune the `Authentication` his test is going to run with. Regarding the "token" suffix to `KeycloakAuthenticationToken`, this is due to Keycloak team sticking to Spring-security naming conventions. So right place to complain about this is spring-security. Good luck.

Comment: And maybe, specially if you're disturbed by the fluent API, you should have a look at the annotations I already mentioned. A sample here: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2-test-webmvc-addons/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc/keycloak/web/GreetingControllerAnnotatedTest.java

Comment: What version do you use? There is no `keycloak.authentication()` (`ServletKeycloakAuthUnitTestingSupport`class does not have this method), I defined `2.3.4` version of your add-on.

Comment: It is in version 2.4.0, as specified in the **EDIT** section of the post: browsing the tag created by maven release plugin, I can find it both in the [controller test](https://git.io/JUupb) and in [ServletKeycloakAuthUnitTestingSupport source](https://git.io/JUuph). In 2.3.4, you should use former method name: `keycloakAuthenticationToken()`